# What's the practical use of Option in rust?

Tags: rust

Consider this example

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut i: Option<i32> = None;
    //after some processing it got some value of 55
    i = Some(55);
    println!("value is {:?}", i.unwrap());
}
```

In go, `nil` represents the zero-value of that type. 
However in rust, it represents absence of a value. How is absence of a value useful in practice?

When a variable with a type is declared, it must have some value either initialized or un-initialized. Why will one declare it to have it absent?

Also please explain, at what point the memory is allocated for `i`  during the initial declaration or when `i` gets some value?

I might be asking a stupid question, but want to get my head around the need of this concept.

Comment: All answers to "When would a variable be nullable" in other languages can answer your question.

Comment: In Go, `nil` doesn't really represent the zero-value of a type. `nil` represents the zero-value of the *pointer* type. The real zero-value for structs is the `make`/`new` version of it.

Comment: In addition to cases where you truly want absence of value, sometimes you might also want an intermediate yet memory safe state of value. For example, if you want to replace a struct field `foo.bar` with `f(foo.bar)`, where `f` is a `Fn(Bar)->Bar`, you need `Option` so that `foo.bar` remains a valid value even if `f` panicks somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How is absence of a value useful in practice?

A simple example is a function that looks for the first matching element in a collection. It may find it, and return it, or not find any.

The [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/index.html) give a few more cases:

> - Initial values
> - Return values for functions that are not defined over their entire input range (partial functions)
> - Return value for otherwise reporting simple errors, where None is returned on error
> - Optional struct fields
> - Struct fields that can be loaned or "taken"
> - Optional function arguments
> - Nullable pointers
> - Swapping things out of difficult situations

Now, you may ask: why don't we use one of the values to mark an empty one? For two reasons:

- There are cases where you do not have a valid "zero-value" or a valid "invalid" value. In this case, you have to use some flag somewhere else to store the fact that something is invalid.
- In general, it is simpler to use the same solution everywhere than having to mark and document which is the "none" value.

> Why will one declare it to have it absent?

This is different than initialized/uninitialized values. `Option` is simply a type that contains either "nothing" (`None`) or a "value" of some type (`Some(value)`)

You can *conceptually* see it as a `struct` with a flag and some space for the value itself.

> Also please explain, at what point the memory is allocated for i during the initial declaration or when  i gets some value?

That depends on the implementation. One could decide to implement `Option` using a pointer to the value, which means it could delay allocating.

However, the most likely implementation is avoiding pointers and keeping the value plus an extra flag. Note that, for some types, you can also optimize further and avoid the flag altogether. For instance, if you have an `Option` of a pointer, you can simply use the zero value for `None`. In fact, Rust does such a thing for types like `Option<Box<T>>`.